renderHook leaking across adjacent tests
I'm having an issue with renderHook leaking across tests.
If I run both test in isolation they work, if I run the whole describe block the second test fails, on the line     expect(result.current.data?.items).toHaveLength(3); with a received length of 5 which clearly suggests that renderHook in the second test is taking the results from the first one.
server.use() is a MSW server and missingValuesMock and listMock are clearly 2 handlers for the worker, the first returns 5 items, the second 3 items.
useCaseListData is a simple Tanstack hook, as you can see below the tests.
My tech stack is next.js 14, Tanstack Query v5, and MWS 2.
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { renderHook, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { server } from '@/lib/http-mocks/server';

import { useCaseListData } from './useCaseListData';

beforeEach(() => {
  server.resetHandlers()
  }
)

describe("test", () => {
  it('fetches case list data with no offset', async () => {
    server.use(listMock);
    const wrapper = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => <QueryWrapper>{children}</QueryWrapper>;

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useCaseListData(0, 5), { wrapper });

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(result.current.isLoading).toBe(false);
    });

    expect(result.current.error).toBe(null);
    expect(result.current.data?.items).toHaveLength(5);
  });


  it('fetches case list with missing values', async () => {
    server.use(missingValuesMock);

    console.log(server.listHandlers())
    const wrapper = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => <QueryWrapper>{children}</QueryWrapper>;

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useCaseListData(0, 5), { wrapper });


    expect(result.current.error).toBe(null);
    expect(result.current.data?.items).toHaveLength(3);

  });

})



export function useCaseListData(page: number, pageSize: number): UseQueryResult<CListDataResult> {
  const result = useQuery<ListDataResult>({
    queryKey: [LIST_KEY, `${page}`, `${pageSize}`],
    queryFn: () => getList(page, pageSize),
    throwOnError: true
  });

  return result;
}


I am having the same issue. Did you solve your problem?

@brubs it was a problem somewhere else in my case.
